# WalletConnect - when QR code is scanned after waiting for 60+ seconds, session response is not received

Tags: .net, wallet-connect

I am using WalletConnectSharp to scan the QR code and connect wallet, which is a c# wrapper for WaleltConnect.

This is sample code from documentation here:
https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectSharp

Build metadata

```
var metadata = new ClientMeta()
{
    Description = "This is a test of the Nethereum.WalletConnect feature",
    Icons = new[] {"https://app.warriders.com/favicon.ico"},
    Name = "WalletConnect Test",
    URL = "https://app.warriders.com"
};
```

Create WalletConnect object
`var walletConnect = new WalletConnect(metadata);`

Show QR code to user
`...`

Wait for user to scan the QR code and receive session response
`var walletConnectData = await walletConnect.Connect();`

Session response is not received when user waits for 60 or more seconds.
However, everything works fine if it's scanned in 59 seconds or less.
WalletConnect's react example dapp https://example.walletconnect.org/ works fine even after 60 seconds, so my thinking is that it's WalletConnectSharp's behavior, but did not find anything in their documentation or code to address it.